# C program to count specific words in FILE

Tags: c

The objective of the program is to rate a person's resume. The program should open and read two .txt type FILES. One of the files contains the keywords and the other is the resume itself. The process of the program consists in looping through the keywords.txt and then try to find a similar word in the resume.txt. I got it almost working but the program seems to be considering the first space as the end of the file in the keywords FILE.
This is what I have:(I tried switching the first word on the keywords and the count seems to work/would be goo to scan only characters without symbols and its necessary to count the occurrence of every single keyword)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){

    FILE*  txtKey;
    FILE* txtResume;
    char keyWords[1000];
    char word[10000];
    int count;

    txtKey=fopen("keywords.txt", "r");
    if(txtKey == NULL){
        printf("Failed to open txtKey file \n");
        return 1;
    }

    txtResume=fopen("resume.txt", "r");
    if(txtResume == NULL){
        printf("Failed to open txtResume file \n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf(txtKey, "%s", keyWords) != EOF) 
    { 
        while (fscanf(txtResume, "%s", word) != EOF) 
        { 
            if (strstr(word, keyWords) != NULL) 
            { 
            count++; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    printf("The keywords were found %d times in your resume!", count);

    fclose(txtResume);
    fclose(txtKey);

    return 0;
}//END MAIN
```

Comment: You have to read the keywords _first_ and store them into a memory array. Then, for each word in the resume file, you have to do `strcmp` on all elements in the array. You have to preread keywords and store them into individual array elements because (e.g.) if the keyword file had `then` but _not_ `the` you don't want a false positive match on `the` from the resume file. You need whole word matching, so that's the reason to use `strcmp` instead of `strstr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note:* This is prefaced by my top comments.

I've created a word list `struct` that holds a list of words. It is used twice. Once, to store the list of keywords. And, a second time to parse the current line of the resume file.

I coded it from scratch, because it's somewhat different than what you had:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
    } while (0)
#endif

typedef struct {
    int list_max;
    int list_cnt;
    char **list_words;
} list_t;

list_t keywords;
list_t linewords;

char buf[10000];

int
wordsplit(FILE *xf,list_t *list,int storeflg)
{
    char *cp;
    char *bp;
    int valid;

    if (! storeflg)
        list->list_cnt = 0;

    do {
        cp = fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),xf);

        valid = (cp != NULL);
        if (! valid)
            break;

        bp = buf;
        while (1) {
            cp = strtok(bp," \t\n");
            bp = NULL;

            if (cp == NULL)
                break;

            // grow the list
            if (list->list_cnt >= list->list_max) {
                list->list_max += 100;
                list->list_words = realloc(list->list_words,
                    sizeof(char *) * (list->list_max + 1));
            }

            if (storeflg)
                cp = strdup(cp);

            list->list_words[list->list_cnt++] = cp;
            list->list_words[list->list_cnt] = NULL;
        }
    } while (0);

    return valid;
}

void
listdump(list_t *list,const char *tag)
{
    char **cur;

    dbgprt("DUMP: %s",tag);

    for (cur = list->list_words;  *cur != NULL;  ++cur) {
        dbgprt(" '%s'",*cur);
    }

    dbgprt("\n");
}

int
main(void)
{
    FILE *xf;
    int count;

    xf = fopen("keywords.txt","r");
    if (xf == NULL)
        return 1;
    while (1) {
        if (! wordsplit(xf,&keywords,1))
            break;
    }
    fclose(xf);
    listdump(&keywords,"KEY");

    count = 0;

    xf = fopen("resume.txt","r");
    if (xf == NULL)
        return 2;
    while (1) {
        if (! wordsplit(xf,&linewords,0))
            break;
        listdump(&linewords,"CUR");

        for (char **str = linewords.list_words;  *str != NULL;  ++str) {
            dbgprt("TRYCUR: '%s'\n",*str);
            for (char **key = keywords.list_words;  *key != NULL;  ++key) {
                dbgprt("TRYKEY: '%s'\n",*key);
                if (strcmp(*str,*key) == 0) {
                    count += 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(xf);

    printf("keywords found %d times\n",count);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Any option to make it simpler? I don't think I know all the concepts of this answer, although tis result is perfect.

Yes, based on your code, I realized that what I did was a bit advanced. But, by reusing the list as I did, it actually saved a bit of replicated code (e.g. Why have separate parsing code for the keywords and resume data when they are both very similar.

There's standard documentation for all the libc functions (e.g. `fgets`, `strtok`, `strcmp`).

If you *know* the [maximum] number of keyword beforehand [this is possible to do], you could use a *fixed* size `char **` array [similar to what you had].

Or, you could just do a `realloc` on a `char **keywords` array on *every* new keyword (e.g. `cp`). And, maintain a separate count variable (e.g. `int keycnt`). This would be fine *if* we only needed *one* list (i.e. we could forego the `list_t` `struct`).

We *could* replicate some of the keyword code for the second loop in `main`, and again, use different variables for the array and its count.

But, this is wasteful. `list_t` is an example of using `realloc` *efficiently* (i.e. calling it less often). This is a standard technique.

If you do a websearch on `dynamic resize array realloc`, one of entries you'll find is: https://newton.ex.ac.uk/teaching/resources/jmr/appendix-growable.html

Note the use of `strdup` to preserve the word values for the keyword list beyond the *next* call to `fgets`.

Hopefully, that covers enough so you can study it a bit. The whole "how to implement a dynamic resizing array using `realloc`?" shows up quite frequently a question on SO, so you could also search here for a question on it.

> Also, how could it word if the keywords.txt list has words separated by ","?

To parse by ",", just change the second arg to `strtok` to include it (e.g. `" \t,\n"`). That will work for `abc def`, `abc,def`, or `abc, def`.

Comment: Any option to make it simpler? I don't think I know all the concepts of this answer, although tis result is perfect. Also, how could it word if the keywords.txt list has words separated by ","?